# Java EE Application client VS Web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, application-client

Application clients seem like second rate citizens in Java EE and I would like input on why?  Eg:

- the Java EE examples have numerous web applications explaining every use case but not a single example of an application client.
- There is very little information or tutorials on google.
- Java EE offers a lot of advantages for application clients as well.

Benefits of application clients:

- No browser that adds a consistent delay to every load (I have clients simply say no to web based applications here).
- More control (Eg. handle internet/network outages)
- Webstart should make it almost as smooth to deploy to users.

Benefits to web applications:

- Runs in the browser, so end users have zero installation.
- Known technologies and patterns etc whith CSS and HTML for developers and familiar browser for users.

So what are the limitations and pro's/con's of each?

Comment: In the end it was easier to use spring so I dropped Java EE altogether.